# How do I install all targets from setup.cfg

Tags: pip

I can do this: `pip install -e ".[test]"`

But how can I do something like this: `pip install -e ".[*]"`?

I have some cases where I just want to install ALL the targets. Is there a way to do that without specifying them individually?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+all+extras